# Sql update column wont regonize diffeent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

The code looks like this but it shows me multipart identifier loty and users could not be found

```
UPDATE zabukowane
SET cenabiletu = zabukowane.cenabagazu + loty.cena
WHERE zabukowane.idlotu = loty.idlotu AND zabukowane.userid = users.userid
FROM zabukowane JOIN loty, users;
```

I want to set column(cenabiletu) in zabukowane to take from table called loty column cena where usersid in users is equal to userid in zabukowane and idlotu in loty is equal to idlotu in zabukowane and adding to cenabagazu and summing that up in cenabiletu column
so it may look like this `cenabiletu.zabukowane=cena.loty+cenabagazu.zabukowane`

Comment: `FROM` goes *before* the `WHERE`, not afterwards. You are also lacking a `ON` for your `JOIN` and are mix and matching ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 JOIN syntax; stick to ANSI-92.

Comment: It also seems that there are a bit too many (unnecessary) tags - [c#] for instance seems unrelated

Comment: sory for taggin too much but to post i needed 5 and i use stackoverflow for first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are missing a few points.
Try it in this way:

```
UPDATE zabukowane
SET cenabiletu = zabukowane.cenabagazu + loty.cena
FROM zabukowane 
INNER JOIN loty on  zabukowane.idlotu = loty.idlotu
Jo
INNER JOIN users on zabukowane.userid = users.userid
```

This post question has a great explanation: [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server).